# How to use Widgets in css

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a widget in WordPress but when I go to my dashboard and click under appearance, I don't see the option Widgets. Can only see Themes,Customize, Menus, Theme check and Editor. What do I do to get Widgets so that I can start creating my own ones?

Comment: add code to the question

Comment: You need to have a sidebar in the theme for widgets to show up.

Comment: @naththedeveloper. Beg your pardon as I have no clue of how to do. 
Do you mean that the Widgets option will show under appearance when I create a sidebar.php?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a sidebar widget first in your `functions.php` file:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );

    function my_register_sidebars() {

        /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'id' => 'primary',
                'name' => __( 'Primary' ),
                'description' => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>'
            )
        );

        /* Repeat register_sidebar() code for additional sidebars. */
    }

?>
```

Then call the widget wherever you want it to show up, either your sidebar or anywhere in your theme.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

    <div id="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The main and remaining problem is that when I go to my wordpress dashboard and click on appearance, the option for Widgets don't show up. Meaning that I cannot even see the default widgets that come with WordPress.
Hoping to have made some sense

Comment: Did you register a sidebar in your functions.php file?

Comment: Yes. I put exactly the same code that is up there in my functions.php and the second code is footer.php